# Dropbox.net get user favorite folder content

Tags: c#, dropbox-api, favorites, directory-listing

I need to know if its possible to list folders and files in "Starred" section of Dropbox? I've tried to get the path "/starred", "starred", "/starred/" or "starred/", but I get an exception that the path is invalid.

```
ListFolderResult listOfFolderItems = await dropboxClient.Files.ListFolderAsync("/starred");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox API unfortunately doesn't offer the ability to get starred files, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

Comment: Yes, propably the way to go is to track application scoped favorites for each user. Thank you for your answer, sir.